# Convert the xml bean config to java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-java-config, openid-connect

I'm basing this [example](https://github.com/lopezoscar/ontrack/blob/1bb747829eb0f9c13b41d5bfa5dc983781303179/OnTrack-Modules/OnTrack-Web/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/security.xml) and trying to build my code in java config. I'm confused with the bean ref. I'm new to spring security and java config for spring.  Can someone explain me this

```
<beans:bean id="preAuthFilter" class="com.sappe.ontrack.security.LoginGoogleFilter">
    <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="preAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService" ref="preAuthUserDeatils" />
</beans:bean>
```

This is part where I get confused, this is not a bean, this is a tag used for spring security.

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="preAuthenticationProvider">
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I have this in my code

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // OpenId connect code....
    ........
    @Bean(name="preAuthFilter")
    public CustomFilter preAuthFilter() {
        return new CustomFilter();
    }

    @Bean(name = "preAuthProvider")
    public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthProvider() {
        return new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    }
    @Bean(name="authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception   {
         return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilter(CustomPreAuthFilter).
            .....//code
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to config all `ref` beans inside xml and then, in java code ,you can get from context